# Protractor for loop issue

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

I have a small problem with for loops in protractor javascript.
When i run a for loop in a for loop. i get first all the console.logs of the first loops and then all the logs of the second loop.

Now when i run the test i get

first loop 0

first loop 1

first loop 2

second loop 0

second loop 1

but this isn't what i expected. i want
first loop 0

second loop 0

second loop 1

first loop 1

......

```
     element.all(by.css('.settings__group .settings__sub-title')).count().then(function(count)
            {
                for(var j = 0; j < count;j++)
                {
                      console.log('first loop ' + j);
                      browser.sleep(2000);
                element.all(by.className('settings__group')).get(j).all(by.className('settings__item')).count().then(function (c) {


                for (let i = 0; i < c; i++) {
                        console.log('second loop ' + i);
                    browser.sleep(1000);
                    element.all(by.className('settings__group')).get(j).all(by.className('settings__item')).get(i).click();
                    browser.sleep(1000);
                    element(by.id('crValidationButton')).isPresent().then(function (present) {
                        if (present) {
                            element(by.id('crValidationButton')).click();
                            browser.sleep(2000);
                            v.validationCase();
                            browser.sleep(2000);
                        }
                        else {
                            browser.sleep(2000);
                            v.validationCase();
                            browser.sleep(2000);
                        }
                    });
                    browser.sleep(1500);
                }
            });
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to the Promise inside the protractor.

I am not that fond of For Loop.

What I usually do is to use a recursive function.

```
...function(count) {
    firstLoop(0, count);
});


function firstLoop(j, count) {
    if (j < count) {
        ... {
            secondLoop(0, c);
        }
        firstLoop(j + 1, count);
    }
}


function secondLoop(i, c) {
    if (i < c) {
        ... 
        secondLoop(i + 1, c);
    }
}
```